# Why won't the integerValidation Method work?

Tags: php, oop

In the method `validateType` it will call the method `intgerValidation` why is this giving me a blank page? When I try to run it but when I remove the `intgerValidation` method it works?

```
public function validateType($validateThis, $validationType) {
    $validateThis;
    $validationType;
    if($validationType == 'int') {
        $this->integerValidation($validateThis));
    }
    if($validationType == 'string') {
        echo 'Is String';
    }
    if($validationType == 'email') {
        echo 'Is an Email';
    }

}
public function integerValidation($int) {
    $regex = "/^[0-9]{10}$/";
    if(preg_match($regex, $int)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
        if($this->validateType(1234567890, 'int')) {
            echo 'Hello';
        }
        else {
            echo 'Number does not validate';
        }
```

Comment: off topic : are you aware of the existence of the [validation filters](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP already have builtin functions for checking variable type

- is_array
- is_bool
- is_callable
- is_double
- is_float
- is_int
- is_integer
- is_long
- is_null
- is_numeric
- is_object
- is_real
- is_resource
- is_scalar
- is_string

why dont use them. http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.var.php

Answer (score 2):

You have to put a `return` in the function `validateType`